# Dexie Table Sort

Tags: sorting, indexeddb, dexie

I'm having trouble sorting a dexie table.

It's likely I'm just not understanding a simple conceptual difference between dexie tables vs dexie collections. So my apologies for asking what's probably a simple question.

I have this code that works just fine:

```
1 db.transaction('r', db.TABLE1, function() {
2   return db.TABLE1.where('FIELD1').equals('VALUE1').toArray();
3 }).then(function (passedvar) {
4   for (i=0; i < passedvar.length; i++) {
5     // Do things with passedvar[i]
6   }
7 }).catch...
```

What I'm trying to do is replace line #2 with this code, but it doesn't work:

```
return db.TABLE1.where('FIELD1').equals('VALUE1').reverse().sortBy('FIELD1').toArray();
```

So my goal is just to descending sort the results of a .where query.  If the code above can be altered to work, then great. If I'm doing it all wrong and there's a better way, that's great too.

Thanks everyone,
Frank

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. The problem was that I thought I needed to have .toArray() to be able to iterate through the returned value. I don't.

So, take .toArray() out and everything works exactly as the **very well written** Dexie documentation promised.

Here's what I ended up with for line #2

```
return db.TABLE1.where('FIELD1').equals('VALUE1').reverse().sortBy('FIELD1');
```

That's it!

Frank

Comment: And how do you sort ASC/DESC?

Comment: @jayarjo I ended with ```(await db.table.toArray()).reverse()```